# Failing to create a docker file to run cypress tests on webkit

Tags: docker, cypress, webkit

This is my docker file:

```js
FROM cypress/included:12.16.0

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git curl openssh-client

RUN yarn add -g @aws-amplify/cli@10.5.2 gatsby-cli@4.24.0 mocha mochawesome mochawesome-merge mochawesome-report-generator serve -n wait-on


WORKDIR /e2e

ENV PATH /e2e/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn add cypress

ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/local/playwright-browsers

RUN yarn add playwright
RUN npx playwright install

RUN ls -la $PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH

RUN chmod -R 777 $PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH

ENTRYPOINT [ "/e2e/run-cypress.sh" ]
```

This is the error I get - no matter what I try...

There was an error launching `playwright-webkit`:

```
Executable doesn't exist at /usr/local/playwright-browsers/webkit-1792/pw_run.sh
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team
```

The docker container runs fine on other browsers, but fails on webkit.